# Logstash filter to copy some text from the log message

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat, elk, logstash-filter

I'm currently loggin some text message like this:

```
"Some text: some variable text"
"Some other text: some other variable text"
```

And I need to copy the variable part of the message to a new field, in order to have two new fields like this

```
"field1" : " some variable text"
"field2" : "some other variable text"
```

So far only been able to copy the entire text message to a new field with the filebeat processors, and the same with logstash. I've done some research and I saw I mightbe able to use conditionals, and with the mutate filter:

```
filter {
  if "Some text" in [message] {
    mutate { add_field =>{ "field1" => }}}
```

But I'vent found how to copy the "some variable text" into the new field. Does someone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use directly [grok](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) filter like this :

```
  filter{
    grok {
        match => { 
          "message" => "^Some text: %{GREEDYDATA:field1}" 
          }
    }
   grok {
        match => { 
          "message" => "^Some other text: %{GREEDYDATA:field2}" 
          }
    }
}
```

The advantage is this is more readable and more easy to maintain than *if* condition.

You can change the grok to handle all case in one line :

```
      filter{
        grok {
            match => { 
              "message" => "^(Some text: %{GREEDYDATA:field1}|Some other text: %{GREEDYDATA:field2})" 
              }
        }
}
```

Comment: Ok the main issue is that I have like 5 log messages that I want to create custom fields, and not to mess with the rest of the log messages. That's why I was considering the conditionals, but my issue is how to implement that.

Comment: I've change my solution to match with your use case

Comment: It seems it's failing to create the fields... I did follow your tutorial, but since I have the logs going to filebeat, I don't know why is falling to create the field.

Comment: Coud you give an example data line? It's probably that the GEEDYDATA doesn't match the  full string.

Comment: The variable data is either some like "rock-and-roll" or "Rock and Roll".

Comment: Ok it must work, but be carrefull with the space in match expression for example and/or remove the ? at the end and the ^ at the beginng

Comment: I already tried the two ways and I'm still not exactally sure why is falling.

Comment: Send me a full line of what must be parsed please

Comment: Hi ended you using the grok processor with the ingest node pipeline instead and it worked like a charm. Thanks for the help.